# onRestoreInstanceState is not called when custom views are generated programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, savestate

I have an application where all the UI comes from a server, so the views are all custom and generated programmatically. Additionally, I have to remove all the views and re-create them when the device is rotated.

In one of my custom views I save the state and it's called on device rotation:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable = Bundle().apply {
    putInt("selectedTabPosition", tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)
    putParcelable("superState", super.onSaveInstanceState())
}
```

In my Fragment, I can see the saved state exists after device rotation. So I `view?.restoreHierarchyState(state)` in the fragment to call all children `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
                   
      // Get the UI from serve, build the UI...
     savedInstanceState?.getSparseParcelableArray<Parcelable>("android:view_state")?.let { state ->
           view?.restoreHierarchyState(state)
     }
}
```

The `view?.restoreHierarchyState(state)` is called with the proper state. But `onRestoreInstanceState` is not called in my custom view (which exists in the view hierarchy)